# SQL errors in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have to admit that I have done very little to try to understand the reason behind the below error. The reason is that I am trying to execute this SQL query in Python and use the output in a much larger project that is much more urgent, and I can't try to study SQL for pandas right now. The below code runs on SQL server.

I naively thought that just passing it to the server using pandas would work just the same. It didn't; it gave me errors along the line of the ones shown at the bottom. Would anyone please point me in the right direction.

```
import pyodbc
import os
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; SERVER=SERVER1.cc.net; Trusted_Connection=yes')

   sql1 = "select case when AP.IS_C_ACCOUNT = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end  as  Account_C_Indicator , A.acct as AcctNum, coalesce(AGT.LegacyPGType,'NONRG') as AcctG_Type,
    coalesce(AGT.Description,'NONRgdD') as AccountType,  case when A.acct_type in (4) then 'CName' else 'Nom' end as AccountHS,
    case when FBM.[F B Cat] is not null then FBM.[F B Cat]  else 'CmAccount' end as AccountRType,
    case when FBM.[Account Type] is not null        then FBM.[Account Type]         else 'CmAccount' end as AccountRBrand,
    case when FBM.[Man Name] is not null        then FBM.[Man Name]         else '' end as AcctPortType,A.open_date as AccountSetupDate,
    case when DATEPART(dayofyear, getdate()) < DATEPART(dayofyear, A.open_date) then YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(A.open_date) - 1 else YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(COALESCE(A.open_date, 0)) end  as AccountTYears
    from SERVER1.DB1.dbo.TABLE_C as A
    inner join SERVER1.DB1.dbo.TABLE_P as AP            on AP.acct = A.acct 
    left join SERVER1.DB1.dbo.TABLE_K as KYC            on KYC.ACCT_NUM = A.acct
    left join SERVER1.DB2.dbo.TABLE_G as AGT            on AGT.AcctSType = A.acct_sub
    left join SERVER1.DB2.dbo.TABLE_M as FBM    on FBM.[Man Code] = A.port_type"

 df = pd.read_sql_query(sql1, conn)

    Errors:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2020, in SQLiteDatabase.execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2019 try:
    -> 2020     cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
       2021     return cur
    
    ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'SERVER1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [13], in <cell line: 13>()
          1 sql1 = "...
    
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql1, conn)
    
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:399, in read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize, dtype)
        341 """
        342 Read SQL query into a DataFrame.
        343 
       (...)
        396 parameter will be converted to UTC.
        397 """
        398 pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con)
    --> 399 return pandas_sql.read_query(
        400     sql,
        401     index_col=index_col,
        402     params=params,
        403     coerce_float=coerce_float,
        404     parse_dates=parse_dates,
        405     chunksize=chunksize,
        406     dtype=dtype,
        407 )
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2080, in SQLiteDatabase.read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize, dtype)
       2068 def read_query(
       2069     self,
       2070     sql,
       (...)
       2076     dtype: DtypeArg | None = None,
       2077 ):
       2079     args = _convert_params(sql, params)
    -> 2080     cursor = self.execute(*args)
       2081     columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
       2083     if chunksize is not None:
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2032, in SQLiteDatabase.execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2029     raise ex from inner_exc
       2031 ex = DatabaseError(f"Execution failed on sql '{args[0]}': {exc}")
    -> 2032 raise ex from exc
```

Comment: It depends on your data types, but `COALESCE(A.open_date, 0)` is extremely suspicious. I would expect that to return an error similar to `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date`. SQL Server Native Client 11.0 hasn't been updated or used in over a decade, though, so who knows what it does?

Comment: Your actual error is "Incorrect syntax near 'SERVER1'". I wonder if the best approach is to get a SQL Server query window on a test database, paste the query in there, and get it working there before transferring it to your Python code.

Comment: @halfer. Thanks! The query works perfectly fine in SQL studio. I honestly (naively) thought I would just send it to SQL from Python, and it would work just the same!

Comment: I don't use Python or SQL Server, but I would expect using the same query should be fine. Consider putting in a very simple query (SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable) and then slowly expand towards your full large query. In so doing you should be able to find out what it does no like.

Comment: Based on the first comment, perhaps you can upgrade your client too?

Comment: @halfer. Thanks. I did early on run "Select top 2000 from table1" and everything worked fine. I then pasted in the entire query, and, boom... :) I guess I will keep building up very slowly. It will take much precious time, but I guess I have to figure it out. As for the client, I don't know. I mean, that's what got installed and works for everything. I didn't purposely go choose it. I'm afraid if I tamper with it, something else breaks ...

Comment: Remove `SERVER1` from query line `from SERVER1.DB1.dbo.TABLE_C as A` and subsequent line too. You don't need 4 part naming unless you are accessing to a linked server

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks. It actually is a linked server :) Anyway, I removed it, and I still got the errors. I'm working on another solution that doesn't involve Python, just in case, and since I have a limited time, but it would be very helpful if I know the way to get this working.